# Why do my legs begin to itch during my running warm up?

Tags: running, warm-up, legs

For as long as I can remember, my legs will start to itch when I begin jogging. Sometimes the itching is unbearable and I have to stop. I noticed that it doesn't happen during sprinting / high intensity interval work. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What kind of clothing are you wearing? Because I always have this on my back and blame those darn hairs rubbing against the functional clothing!

Comment: @Ivo: it happens with everything: shorts, sweats, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Itching/tingling indicates an increase in bloodflow due to expanded capillaries and arteries. This problem should go away as you increase your level of physical fitness. If the itching comes with a rash though, it's more likely to be exercise-induced anaphylaxis (an allergic reaction).